Skip job if only mentioned folder modified in gitlab yml
I have gitlab yml job which running fine. I want to skip running a job if mentioned folder only modified.
I have around 20 to 30 folders in code base. If any other folder modified with the mentioned folder the job needs to run. Only it has to skip if the only mentioned modified.
I,m trying to use the below snipped but it will run based on changed files.
rules:
- if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event" && $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "develop"
  changes: 
    paths:
      - "**/*"
  when: manual

Above I have mentioned everything **/*, now I want to exclude only specific folder.
